# Using UICollectionView inside regular UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, collectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a regular view that I want to use half of with with `UICollectionView`.
I dragged and resized the `UICollectionView` onto the View. I the dragged a `UICollectionViewCell` new the view and designed it (all in XCode the layout builder).

The `UICollectionViewCell` class is called `ImageCell` so I on my `viewDidLoad` event I registered the cell class to the `UICollectionView`:

```
[self.imagesCollectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImagePhotoCell"];
```

This is how I try to load the images to the collection view cells:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
ImageCell *imageCell = [imagesCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImagePhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
imageCell.CellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_2284.JPG"];
return imageCell;
```

}

The `CellImageView` is a `IBOutlet` of a `UIImageView`.
I know I'm trying to load the same image - this is only for testing. The image is stored in the Supporting Files folder.

The problem is all I get is a black screen. No images are shown. I know I'm loading the image correctly because I tried to do the same for a regular ImageView and it worked.

Comment: Have you implemented the rest of the datasource methods? What layout are you using? Is the cellForItem.. Method being called?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and it appears to be a result of the NIB not being loaded.
Try replacing the viewDidLoad register call with the following:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibFileName" bundle:nil];
[self.imagesCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImagePhotoCell"];
```